# Facebook Login Button Behaving Strangely

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing an application which on login page also supports facebook login with

```
<fb:login-button>.
```

I have set up two Apps on facebook:

1. one for localhost (Web site url http://localhost/, no App Domain)
2. one for testing server (Web site url http://dev.domain.com/, no App 
   Domain)

When I am developing on my own computer click on login button operates as expected and I am logged into my application.
When I put my application to the server (change appid and secret to use 2nd App) and click login button the facebook login dialog opens and when I enter email and password it closes but my applciation does not log me in.
Whats more if I check on server I see that process which is handling this web request is constantly increasing memory size (3MB per second) and its taking 50% or more CPU time. If this process is not stopped soon the server becomes unresponsive becouse memory used by it is maximum possible and CPU time is 100%.
This happens as soon as facebook login dialog closes.

In my application I am using library facebook C# SDK from codeplex.

If anyone has any information on what I might be doing wrong O would greatly appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem...it was not about facebook but .Net Framework. It appears that some versions of framework support parameter passing from dynamic objects and others don't.
So when i changed code from

```
dynamic fbuser = GetUserData();
DoSomethingWithID(fbuser.id);
```

to

```
dynamic fbuser = GetUserData();
object fbid = fbuser.id;
DoSomethingWithID(fbid);
```

it started to work...dont really understand why sometimes even on the server it would work (after remote debugging it always worked until dll's were replaced but ...dont really care :) )

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an infinite redirect loop.

Check to see what your browser is doing using Firefox's Firebug or a built-in developer tool for Chrome, IE or Safari.  I think there might be a setting wrong in your app settings, and by looking at the traffic it might help lead us to the culprit.

Comment: Firebug shows that after dialog closes it makes a POST request to my login page with cookie information (ASP.NET_SessionId=21c0udax0ped2ziz0g5epyin; fbsr_131653813577722 ...) and after about 1 minute it aborts. After the abort server process keeps running on 50%+ CPU time and keeps increasing memory. Is there any other information i could give you from firebug?

Comment: If there's only one call to your webserver, put a breakpoint in and start stepping thru to see where the issue is.  Another good technique is to download the source code of the Facebook C# SDK and add the project to your solution and reference the project and not the compiled dlls, so you can step into the SDK.  I had to do this for one issue I had with it.  Good luck!

Comment: When i started remote debugging (since on my computer this works and problem only happens on server) it started to work and it kept on working. When i updated server with new version of my app (which again was working on my computer) the same error happened. What is even more frustrating is that the same code is used to check for identification (FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated()) on another page in the application and it works there (even on server).

Comment: When i inspected the network traffic on server i see that there is a constant communication from my server to graph.facebook.com and other way around.

Comment: This is what i found out so far: if i remote debug my applciation everything works fine. When i stop remote debugging the process never ends.